# Has HSQLDB some mechanism to save in-memory data to file?

Tags: hsqldb

Has HSQLDB some mechanism for saving in-memory data to file?

As I know after the server is shutted down, all in-memory data become unaccessible. So I want to save all in-memory data to file.
Unfortunately I can't use BACKUP mechanism, because it can't be applied for in-memory data.

Comment: I too want this feature. The fact that there isn't goes against "Unix Philosophy" where text should be pipeable into and out of a process. Bloatware wins again.

Answer (score 9):

HSQLDB databases are of different types. The all-in-memory databases do not store the data to disk. These databases have URLs in the form `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:<name>`.

If your database URL is in the form `jdbc:hsqldb:file:<file path>` and your tables are the default MEMORY tables, the data is all in memory but the changes are written to a set of disk files.

With all types of database, including all_in_memory, you can use the SQL statement `SCRIPT <file path>` to save the full database to a file. If you save the data to a file with the `.script` extension, you can open the file as a file database.

When you run a server, the URL's are used without the `jdbc:hsqldb` prefix, for example `server.database.0=file:C:/myfile`

See the guide here http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#running_db-sect

Comment: Does HSQLDB write any temporary files to disk and then delete them, when I am using db URL as jdbc:hsqldb:mem:<name> , and I am inserting a row into a table? I am deploying my Java Mule ESB application to cloudhub. It works fine on local but not on cloud. It seems cloudhub does not allow writing files. Application works fine when I comment out db insert and return dummy response.

Comment: A mem: database (URL jdbc:hsqldb:mem:<name>) does not write anything to the file system.

Comment: @fredt if we exclude temp files

Answer (score 7):

There is an SQL command for that. Try this:

```
SCRIPT '/tmp/data.sql'
```

See [here](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#N144AE) for details.